# VBA Iteration vs SQL Speed in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update

Goal: I have a bunch of dates, I want to update the records of the minimum date by category:

```
JVID    APDATE      TAG     into >      JVID    APDATE      TAG
1       201501      Use                 1       201501      Don't Use
1       201502      Use                 1       201502      Use
1       201502      Use                 1       201502      Use
1       201503      Use                 1       201503      Use
2       201502      Use                 2       201502      Don't Use
2       201503      Use                 2       201503      Use
```

The method I'm using is as follows:
I create a dictionary where the Key = ID, and Value = MinDateByID
Then I loop thorough the keys (for each key in dictionary) and run an update query for each ID that checks an IIF statement updating Use/Don't Use based on the date matching the min date.

This works, but w/ +80k IDs covering +1M records it takes forever.

I'm considering running the same thing, but dumping SQL and just iterating through the records, but I can't imagine that'd be faster?

I'm looking for SQL or VBA suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT - Added SQL From Comments**
`UPDATE [FY16 Q12 BE] SET [FY16 Q12 BE].[Record Use] = IIF([FY16 Q12 BE].[Date] = "201601", "Use", "Don't Use") WHERE ([FY16 Q12 BE].[ID]="20165645699");`

> I look through each of the dictionary key/value pairs ex (20165645699, 201601)
>   creating and running this script in various forms 80k+ times

Comment: This is the sort of thing SQL does well, but I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to have one 'Use' on the earliest date for each ID, or what ?

Comment: @grahmaj42 Yes, I want "Use" on the earliest date, sometimes the earliest date is repeated multiple times also and all of those items should be marked use. I thought this was a pretty clear cut SQL application, but my script is so very slow -- several hours and still not finished.

Comment: What SQL are you usng that "takes forever"?

Comment: @dbmitch

UPDATE [FY16 Q12 BE] SET [FY16 Q12 BE].[Record Use] = IIF([FY16 Q12 BE].[Accounting Period] = "201601", "Include", "Dup Perm JV") WHERE ([FY16 Q12 BE].[ID]="20165645699");

I look through each of the dictionary key/value pairs essentially creating and running this script in various forms 80k times

Comment: My SQL statement isn't slow, but this method is slow.

Comment: The columns and data doesn't look at all like your data example? Are you looking for SQL that matches your example - or do you want to revise your sample dataset?

Comment: I can't share my data, so I made up example data. The only difference in my SQL statement is Accounting Period = Date and Use/Don't Use = Include/Dup Perm JV.

UPDATE [FY16 Q12 BE] SET [FY16 Q12 BE].[Record Use] = IIF([FY16 Q12 BE].[Date] = "201601", "Use", "Don't Use") WHERE ([FY16 Q12 BE].[ID]="20165645699");

I'm looking for a solution (SQL Statement) that doesn't require looping through the dictionary pairs, in this example (20165645699, 201601) as I believe that's the choke point.

Comment: If you're going to add new SQL and data - please edit your question and add it up there. It's unreadable in comments area

Comment: Better approach would be to add a reference to ado, and run your existing SQL statement through ado instead of dao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on an iterative approach - I'm not sure why it's so much faster than the SQL options outline above, but it does the trick. Thank you for your feedback.

```
Sub MinAPInclude(ByVal Tablename As String)
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strList As String
Dim JVMinAP As Dictionary
Set JVMinAP = New Dictionary
Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

If Not DoesFieldExist(Tablename, "APDate") Then Exit Sub
SQLStatement = "SELECT [" & Tablename & "].[JVID], Min([" & Tablename & "].[APDate]) AS TargetAP"
SQLStatement = SQLStatement & " FROM [" & Tablename & "]"
SQLStatement = SQLStatement & " GROUP BY [" & Tablename & "].[JVID];"

Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("", SQLStatement)
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    If Not IsNull(rs("JVID")) Then
        If Not JVMinAP.Exists(CStr(rs("JVID"))) Then
            MinAP = rs("TargetAP")
            JVMinAP.Add CStr(rs("JVID")), MinAP
        End If
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(Tablename)
rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    If rst("Record Use") <> "Include" Then
        If rst("APDate") = JVMinAP(CStr(rst("JVID"))) Then
            rst.Edit
                rst("Record Use") = "Include"
            rst.Update
        End If
    End If
rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set qd = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is more restrictive than mainstream databases in joined updates, so I had to use a temporary table T2 to hold the minimum values.

`SELECT T1.ID, MIN(T1.RDate) AS MinDate INTO T2
FROM Test1
GROUP BY T1.ID;`

Now I can perform the joined update:

`UPDATE T1 LEFT JOIN T2
     ON T1.ID=T2.ID AND T1.RDate=T2.MinDate;`

Finally, I drop the temporary table :

`DROP T2;
SET TAG = IIF(T2.ID IS NULL, "Don't Use", "Use");`

[I have named your table T1 and the date field RDate to avoid a conflict with a reserved word.]

This could be speeded up further by adding a primary key to T2 on (ID, MinDate) and an index on T1 on (ID, RDate).

Comment: Makes sense, let me implement and I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with one update query - or at least a combination of multiple queries in one SQL statement.

I'm going to use your example data, since I can't figure out what your actual table or field names are in your comments.

You need to replace Table4 with your table name - and ID/Date/Tag fields to match your column names.

**UPDATE SQL:**

```
UPDATE Table4 SET Table4.Tag = "Don't Use"
WHERE ([Date] & "-" & [ID]) 
In (SELECT MergeID FROM 
    (SELECT Mins.[MinOfDate] & "-" & [ID] AS MergeID
        FROM 
        (SELECT Table4.ID, Min(Table4.Date) AS MinOfDate
            FROM Table4
            WHERE Table4.Tag="Use"
            GROUP BY Table4.ID) AS Mins) AS Merges);
```

If you don't need the criteria to only check TAGs that haven't been changed then you can eliminate the criteria `WHERE Table4.Tag="Use"`

**OTHER 'No Tag Check' OPTION**

**UPDATE SQL:**

```
UPDATE Table4 SET Table4.Tag = "Don't Use"
WHERE ([Date] & "-" & [ID]) 
In (SELECT MergeID FROM 
    (SELECT Mins.[MinOfDate] & "-" & [ID] AS MergeID
        FROM 
        (SELECT Table4.ID, Min(Table4.Date) AS MinOfDate
            FROM Table4
            GROUP BY Table4.ID) AS Mins) AS Merges);
```

Comment: I used the bottom query on my table -- 800k records
It's been running for an hour

Comment: Do you have an index on Date field?

Comment: It's been running for about 3:15, and the progress bar is ~20%, that's a flag that this isn't a viable solution.

No, the date field has not been indexed - I'll try that now.

Comment: Phewhh. Almost time for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest this. But I see you have duplicate dates and I'm not sure how you intend to handle these when you have ties for the earliest date.

```
update [FY16 Q12 BE]
set TAG = "Don't use"
where not exists (
    select 1 from [FY16 Q12 BE] as t2
    where t2.ID = [FY16 Q12 BE].ID and t2.[DATE] < [FY16 Q12 BE].[DATE]       
)
```